# 2D Eyes Overlapping Unintentionally

Tags: texturing

So I've got all my model's eyes drawn & assigned to a number, etc. I noticed when the eyes start cycling through the closing pngs that the original eye is acting as a sort of mask underneath? I want the last 2 eyes specifically to be transparent (closing.png & closed.png or 5 & 6) and I'm unsure what I've done that's resulted in this error.

(GIF of what it looks like right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXlad.jpg )

I've been following this tutorial and I'm not sure where I deviated since his eye textures seem to be working: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-GtAFAfe5tU&ab_channel=TheObservatory (Skip to 2:37-ish to see him cycle through his eyes)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**The Reason** for the problem is that all eye texture images use the mask of the *default eyes* to mix the color of the eyes and the color face. This works for all of them except for the *closed eyes*. For the *closed eyes* this fails because requires a different mask to exclude the eyelids that are the eyeball for all other images. In the case of the *closed eyes* you must use the alpha mask that comes with this image.

In the image editor, you can display the channels individually to check them out. Use the last drop-down menu to choose the channel:

Here you see the eye images and their alpha masks. The top left image shows only the *Color*, the top right one shows *Color and Alpha*. Both images at the bottom are the *Alpha* channels/masks.
[image: eye images and their alpha masks]

**It's All Black** and the closed eyes are barely visible because the face is almost black, the eyelashes are black, and the eyelids are also black because of the used mask.

(Side note: The eyelids are black because the image's *Alpha* option is set to *Straight* (default). This renders any transparent (background) pixels black even if the background is white here. If you need the real color use *Channel-packed*. The background (=color of the eyelids of the closed eyes) is visible because you took the mask of the open eyes.)

**A Possible Solution** to fix the shader is to use the *Alpha* mask of the *closed eyes* for the *closed eyes*. A quick and dirty way is to add another *MixRGB* node for the Alpha mask. It's a bit "dirty" because if you add another image with open eyes that requires the default alpha mask you need to swap the order of the images or adjust the condition for the selection of the alpha mask. Ideally, you would use the individual alpha mask for each image. However, this would greatly bloat the node setup.

**Time to Clean Up the *Eyes* Node Group**. There is no need to have several input slots for the image threshold value (*Value*) as shown in the tutorial because the value is always the same. With a *Reroute* node you can organize the connection lines. (Use <kbd>G</kbd> to grab and move the *Reroute* node.)

In the side panel of the *Shader* editor, you can remove the unnecessary slots, give the slot a proper name and limit the value range. Then you can also remove the other dummy node group that just limits the value range.

**Get Some Contrast**, you need to increase the *Brightness* of the face a tiny bit. Also, increase the *Roughness* value and lower the *Specular* value of the *Principled BSDF* to get more contrast and make the black eyelashes visible. Otherwise, you won't see them ;-)

The shader for the head:

[image: shader for the eyes and head]

The adjusted *Eyes* node group:

[image: node group Eyes]

**For animation**, you need to set the *Interpolation Mode* to *Constant* to keep the image threshold values constant (*Graph Editor*, then context menu).

[image: example animation]

Comment: Hi! So how did you add that "Type: Float" option to your group input? I'm trying to follow along with what you've outlined here and you seem to have a much better grasp on nodes than me.

Comment: Hi. Select the *Group Input* node,  open the side-panel in the *Shader Editor* (key N), and select the *Group* tab. It's one of the vertical tabs on the right side. There you have the input slots as shown on the screenshot. With [+] and [-] you can add and remove input slots, and choose the type, like *Float*. The same you can do for the output slots. It works like other lists such as the vertex group list, UV maps, material list.

Comment: I'm in the group panel after selecting the group input node, but the only values I can change are "name, default, min, & max" and there is no option for type.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. This is new in Blender 3.0 and not present in 2.9. In Blender 2.9 you have to drag a node that has the correct type to the group input/output to create a slot of that type. I think that you cannot change it once it's created.